# Wrapper height adjustable as per screen resolution

Tags: css, styling

is there any way to auto adjust height of  as per screen resolution , below line i have written but if screen resolution is 80% it show white space at bottom,

```
wrapper: {
    height: '63vh',
    position: 'relative',
    backgroundColor: 'white'    
  },
```

Comment: How long are you trying to set the wrapper to be?

Comment: it should be adjustable to screen height 63v work for 100% , but if i reduced screen resolution it come 1 inch blank space at bottom,so any way it get increase when i reduce resolution

Comment: Please use 100vh for 100%. Also if you are using any header and footer then you need to reduce that height. For Example height : calc(100vh - header/footer height).
Or it will be great if you can share the code of url.